# How to use hwcrypto.js check persons use usb-token

Tags: javascript

I am currently developing a web based signing system use [hwcrypto](https://github.com/hwcrypto/hwcrypto.js)
When user plug usb-token device to computer then click button, it prompt select certificate and enter password:

```
window.hwcrypto.getCertificate({lang: lang, filter: filter})
.then(function(cert) {
    window.hwcrypto.sign(cert, {type: hashtype, hex: hash}, {lang: lang})
    .then(function(signature){
        // call jquery ajax to do some important thing
        $.ajax({
            url: 'index.php?action=very_important_action',
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
        });
    });
});
```

It works, but i worry users call ajax function directly not use usb-token. How can I protect that?

Comment: Refer to this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63173083/9659885) for complete documentation of Javascript APIs provided by free Signer.Digital Browser Extension

Answer (score 1):

I have a few approaches in mind, but it depends on your implementation -

1. You can set the usb-token in your local storage, and the page that is being requested has the check that usb-token field should already be available in the local storage.
2. You can check for every ajax request that is being made, by using `$.ajax.beforeSend` and check if you have usb-token available.
3. You can send the token as a query parameter and check in the page that is being requested, that if the parameter containing the token exists or not.